# custom word in custom permalink structure

Tags: posts, permalinks

I can see that there is a custom structure option which has things like %year%, %postname% etc. but how can I put my own one there? I would like something like:

```
https://example.com/latest-news/%postname%
```

Comment: You can just type it in, no need to do anything special.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If you make that an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just type it in, no need to do anything special.